# Integration test Service layer Play Framework

Tags: playframework-2.0

Im using Play Framework 2.0 - given I have a PaymentService which access the databases.

Today I test this by first firing up the test server:

```
// set up and start the fake web application
FakeApplication fakeApp = fakeApplication(inMemoryDatabase());
start(fakeApp);
// get the JPAPlugin through the fake app, and start it
Option<JPAPlugin> jpaPlugin = fakeApp.getWrappedApplication().plugin(JPAPlugin.class);
jpaPlugin.get().onStart();
// then through the JPA plugin, get access to the entity manager
final EntityManager manager = jpaPlugin.get().em("default");
// and bind it in the thread local
JPA.bindForCurrentThread(manager);
JPA.em().getTransaction().begin();
```

After this is done I can start accessing the database, insert pre state, execute the methods on the service, and assert (DB) post state

But it doesnt feel right to fire up the whole web server (even if its a fake server) when I test the service layer only to get access to the Entity Manager.

Is there a smarter way to integration test the service layer? 
Coming from a Spring world, I would assume it should be possible to create the Entity Manager manually instead of having the Play server doing it for us.

Any help / tips / directions appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using [TestServer](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/java/play/test/TestServer.html) class as well as [Helpers](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/java/play/test/Helpers.html) class. You can use it to run in memory instance of play from junit test and then run fake requests against this instance. The instance and your plugins will be initialized with your application.conf.

Minimal configuration:

```
app = fakeApplication(inMemoryDatabase());
server = Helpers.testServer(9009, app);
webDriver = play.api.test.WebDriverFactory.apply(HTMLUNIT);
Helpers.start(server);
browser = Helpers.testBrowser(webDriver);
```

Actual test:

```
Result result = Helpers.route(Helpers.fakeRequest(GET, "/data..."));
assertNotNull(result);
```

And remember to clean up:

```
browser.quit();
Helpers.stop(server);
```